# What is the recommended delay to put LCD/LED screens to sleep?

Tags: display, power-management

My LCDs and LEDs screens are configured to enter sleep mode after 5 minutes of computer inactivity, and I have being using this setup for years. Today, I was wondering if I could lower this delay, specially on my netbook, used mainly for music playing and downloading.

Can I risk burning the components by lowering this delay? Is there a recommended minimum delay setting or maximum number of daily sleep/waking up cicles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a delay of 30-60min for CCFL backlit LCD monitors, because the CCFL backlight takes awhile to stabilize when turned on. Therefore, you dont really want it going on and off so much. When you are playing music, just turn it off manually. For LED monitors, sure you can lower the delay to whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend ***15 minutes***. I am never wrong, thus this is **the recommended delay**, requiring no futher explanation.

Comment: I use never, which is not recommended but still works. After doing some calculations, I've determined that out of last 3 years, my laptop was on for 2.5 and its screen was on all the time and it works as well as it worked when it was new. Do note that your screen may not be my screen and that I recommend that you stick to the recommended setting which is recommended and therefore recommendable and in general safe to recommend!

Comment: Excellent recommendation, @AndrejaKo.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, in general lights have the same statistical chance of failing after 2 years as the first day. It just slowly happens.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: LCD lights tend to get darker over time... I guess your laptop screen "still works" but it is not as bright as it used to be...

Comment: The argument of using the default is sensible. But, defaults are often very conservative...

Answer (score 2):

I have my desktop screens set to shut off after 15 minutes with no activity. My laptop is less though. It depends on what you use your computer for, and how often you're on it throughout the day. Keep in mind that more power consumption = higher electric bill. So it's usually for the better to have it shut off after a few minutes.

Comment: PS. @tyblu's answer and @Andrejako's comment were awesome! +1